# Hibernate table is not mapped on server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I can not run queries on Linux (Red Hat) server while everything is fine on local machine (Windows 10)

Role class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ROLETREEGROUP",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TREEGROUP_ID") }
    )
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    public Role() { }

    public Role(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }


}
```

BaseDAO:

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> modelClass;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    BaseDAO(Class<T> modelClass) {
        this.modelClass = modelClass;
    }

    protected final Session getSession() {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
           session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        }

        return session;

    }

    protected final Transaction getTransaction(Session session) {
        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        if (!TransactionStatus.ACTIVE.equals(tx.getStatus()))
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

        return tx;
    }

    public final void save(T obj) {
        Session session = this.getSession();
        Transaction tx = this.getTransaction(session);
        session.persist(obj);
        tx.commit();
    }

    public final void delete(T obj) {
        Session session = this.getSession();
        Transaction tx = this.getTransaction(session);
        session.remove(obj);
        tx.commit();
    }

    public final void update(T obj) {
        Session session = this.getSession();
        Transaction tx = this.getTransaction(session);
        session.merge(obj);
        tx.commit();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected final List<T> query(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        Query<T> myQuery = getSession().createQuery(query);

        parameters.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if(value instanceof String) {
                myQuery.setParameter(key, String.valueOf(value));
            }

            if(value instanceof List) {
                myQuery.setParameterList(key, (List) value);
            }
        });

        return myQuery.list();
    }
}
```

RoleDAO:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class RoleDAO extends BaseDAO<Role> {

    public RoleDAO() {
        super(Role.class);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Role> getByTitle(String title) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("title", title);
        return this.query("select distinct r from Role r left join fetch r.groups where r.title = :title", params);
    }
}
```

RoleService:

```
public class RoleService {
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    public RoleService() {
        roleDAO = new RoleDAO();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Role role) {
        roleDAO.save(role);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveAll(Collection<Role> roles) {
        for(Role role: roles) {
            roleDAO.save(role);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Role role) {
        roleDAO.update(role);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Role role) {
        roleDAO.delete(role);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Role> getByTitle(String title) {
        return roleDAO.getByTitle(title);
    }

}
```

HibernateUtil:

```
public final class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateUtil() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated");
}

public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }

    return sessionFactory;
}

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder localSessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource().createDataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(SystemProperties.getProperty(DB_HIBERNATE_ENTITYPACKAGE));

        localSessionFactoryBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        sessionFactory = localSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Hibernate initialization error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

   

}
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Role is not
> mapped [from Role]    at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:757)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) .................................................................................

> ~[?:1.8.0_361] Caused by:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Role is not
> mapped [from Role]    at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:112)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   ... 16 more Caused
> by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Role is not
> mapped    at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:170)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:334)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3782)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3671)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:746)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:602)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:339)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:112)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]   ... 16 more

Again, this code works on local environment and configuration properties are same for local and development server. What could have caused this error on server?
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the error is in the different `DB_HIBERNATE_ENTITYPACKAGE` property, try to debug it on dev server more strictly

Comment: Please add output from this code: `sessionFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities().forEach(System.out::println);`. Add the code in the method `buildSessionFactory()`.

Comment: @Grim I added that code after sessionFactory = localSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(); there was no output. It seems it can not find my entity package.

Comment: @yahorbarkouski thanks for advice. I checked it several times from elastic logs. property is identical for both environments. as Grim suggested i printed scanned entities but they are not there.

Comment: @Grim fiy, there was no output on the linux server. on my local machine output is: 
Group
Role

Answer (score 0):

The value of DB_HIBERNATE_ENTITYPACKAGE does not resolve to the package of entity classes in linux. Either the value is wrong or the classfiles are not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create session using the following HibernateUtil class which allows you to add entity classes using `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(YourEntity.class);`

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {

            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                //hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml properties
                Properties properties = new Properties();

                properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false");
                properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "db_username");
                properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "db_password");
                properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
                properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
                properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    
                configuration.setProperties(properties);

                //Associate/link DB connection with entity objects
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Role.class);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(AnotherEntity.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

                //System.out.println("Hibernate java config service Registry created");
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                return sessionFactory;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```